# What is a regex that will find something and grab what is next to it?

Tags: ruby, regex, parsing

I have a project using the forecast API (forecast.io) and I am using the [forecast.io](https://github.com/czarneckid/forecast.io-ruby/tree/master/lib) wrapper to interact with it. So far as I can tell, the api only returns data like this:

```
{"latitude":37.8267,"longitude":-122.423,"timezone":"America/Los_Angeles","offset":-7,"currently":{"time":1367169220,"summary":"Mostly Cloudy","icon":"partly-cloudy-day","precipIntensity":0,"temperature":59.45,"dewPoint":59.31,"windSpeed":4.38,"windBearing":281,"cloudCover":0.56,"humidity":0.69,"pressure":1017.24,"visibility":9.82,"ozone":326.11},"minutely":{"summary":"Mostly cloudy for the hour.","icon":"partly-cloudy-day","data":[{"time":1367169180,"precipIntensity":0},{"time":1367169240,"precipIntensity":0},{"time":1367169300,"precipIntensity":0},{"time":1367169360,"precipIntensity":0},{"precipIntensity":0,"temperature":58.39,"dewPoint":58.83,"windSpeed":4.23,"windBearing":278,"cloudCover":0.59,"humidity":0.71,"pressure":1017.28,"visibility":9.31,"ozone":326.07},
```

Now, I want to extract information like pressure, or visibility to use an my app. Since there appears to be no API call to just grab that information, I feel I need to sort it out.

Now, how do I write a regular expression to match for something like temperature, and then grab the information in the quotes next to it? I'd like to send specific information from the APi to variables in my app. EDIT: I found out a regex would be a very bad idea. Great call.

Someone has suggested that I might try look ahead, but perhaps I missing some fundamentally easier solution. http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html outlines the technique which was suggested to me.

EDIT: It has correctly been suggested that I parse this as JSON, and that an expression would be a bad idea. I agree and have implemented this this. I'm still curious about ways you could make this happen with a REGEX if anyone has any creative suggestions.

Comment: Sorry, but this seems like JSON, use a JSON parser and you're done.

Comment: This is a Hash seems to me. give it proper way. You can use `pp` to print it properly.then only we can give you good solution.

Comment: Ah well the JSON parsing stuff does help quite a bit. If I had to be dumb and do things the hard way, is there way to do it with Regex? Now I'm curious.

Comment: It is not a well formed JSON, it is only a fragment of JSON, so it cannot be parsed correctly, even in the dumb way. -1 for sloppyness.

Comment: @baordog Ok, check this [regex out](http://rubular.com/r/NEU1rARBQ0) and I hope you won't use it on production since it's unstable and can't arrange the output in an array style. [This regex](http://regex101.com/r/jO2nQ0) is the same one but hosted elsewhere.

Comment: Parsing JSON with a regular expression is a losing proposition because JSON can be formatted too many different ways. It would be like trying to parse HTML or XML using regular expressions, something that is also unlikely to work well over time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The format you're seeing here is, as far as I can tell and as far as can be expected, valid JSON. You shouldn't use regexes to parse JSON. Use a JSON library. In ruby, one is built-in. It seems you actually want:

```
require "json"

...

data = JSON.parse json_data # json_data is what the API service returns

temperature = data["currently"]["temperature"]
visibility  = data["currently"]["visibility"]
pressure    = data["currently"]["pressure"]
...
```

---

However, the `forecast.io` wrapper you're using seems to do all the parsing for you, and to return an object that should be accessed as such:

```
require "forecast_io"
...
data = Forecast::IO.forecast ...

...

temperature = data.currently.temperature
visibility  = data.currently.visibility
pressure    = data.currently.pressure
...
```

Comment: This is great, and got me close. It seems that the whoever made the wrapper for this put things through hashie, and JSON doesn't like that. I get an error like "Can't conver Hashie::Marsh into string" - any ideas for dealing with/fixing that?

Comment: @baordog perhaps `Hashie::Marsh` should be treated like `data` in my sample, or with symbols for keys (`data[:currently][:pressure]`)? Hashie seems to be pretty much merely an extension of Ruby's native Hashes like JSON returns.

Comment: @baordog the documentation of forecast.io is pretty weak, but also try `data.currently.pressure` and the like.

Comment: @baordog which one, `data.currently.pressure`?

Comment: Yes. That one is working pretty well. I'm still interested in learning how to get past the Hashie thing. I'm aware that Hashie is alternative way to deal with Hashes in ruby, but I don't know how to mutate that in to a format the JSON parser will accept.

Comment: @baordog it seems that what you're getting from the wrapper has been already parsed into an object. No need to parse that again if the wrapper does (which you claimed it didn't)